# R - Starting at a palette color different from the 1st

Tags: r, points, palette

I am plotting points using the code:

```
with(data, point(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, pch = 21, bg = Fatal, col = cluster)
```

Where `Fatal` is a factor with 2 levels (Y, N) and `cluster` is a factor of 3 levels (1, 2, 3).

I have defined a color palette of 5 colors:

```
palette(c(rgb(255, 165, 0, alpha = 120, max = 255),
          rgb(211, 211, 211, alpha = 120, max = 255),
          rgb(255, 0, 0, alpha = 120, max = 255),
          rgb(0, 0, 0, alpha = 255, max = 255),
          rgb(255, 255, 255, alpha = 255, max = 255)))
```

I want to create the points such that the background color will use the first 2 colors in the palette and the border will use the last 3 colors in the palette.

Is there any way to either:

1) create 2 different color palettes to use in a `points()` command?

2) tell R to use the last 3 colors in the palette for `col = cluster`?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you plan to assign 3 colors to 2 levels?

Comment: I meant to say that `cluster` was a factor with 3 levels. It's corrected now.

Comment: maybe separate the big palette and just make two smaller palettes, one for`fill` and `color` with your desired orders.